# Get the last ids with multiple inserts in one query a MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to add multiple records to a database in one query, I use the following command:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO db (name, value) VALUES 
        ('name', 'value'),
        ('name', 'value'),
        ('name', 'value'),
        ('name', 'value'); ");
?>
```

Everything works great, but I want immediately after the command to get the id of these files, the default function is `mysqli_insert_id($db);`
But the problem is that it displays the last added id.

The problem is that I have a lot of traffic on the page every now and then a new insert. I'm afraid downloading the recently added records as a `SELECT` query may not be a good idea since they can download other id inserts.

Comment: But if you get the last id I think it is enough; say your last id is ```n``` then the ids of the newly inserted rows will be:  [n, n-1, n-2, n-3] if you are using auto increment ids

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the help :)